# Вычисление значений рядных функций

Tags: c++

[image: функция]
    Здравствуйте! Мне был дан для вычисления такой ряд, я написала программу, однако преподаватель потребовал сделать ее без рекурсии для факториала и степени -1, так как неэффективно используется память. Нужно использовать частное от последующего и предыдущего члена суммы (Zn - Zn+1) и для остановки счета рядов необходимо использовать следующее условие: |F(xn )| < eps, но я не понимаю, как это воплотить в программу, очень прошу вашей помощи!

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double MyCos(double, double);
double fact(int);
int OneP(int);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    double eps, d, x, x_start, x_end, dx, x_ideal;// невязка, погрешность - остановка расчета, начальный х, конечный х, 
    //шаг вычисления, х для вычисления значений различной точностью
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Введите точность эпсилон: ";
        cin >> eps;
        if (eps <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Точность должна быть вещественным положительным числом" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }

        cout << "Введите начальный x_start: ";
        cin >> x_start;
        x = x_start;

        cout << "Введите конечный x_end: ";
        cin >> x_end;

        cout << "Введите интервал delta_x: ";
        cin >> dx;

        if (dx <= 0 || eps < 0)
        {
            cout << "Введите верные данные" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }

        else if (x_start >= x_end)
        {
            printf(" ______________ ___________________ ____________________ ______________ \n");
            printf("|_______x______|___MyFunction(x)___|_____x*cos(3*x)_____|_______d______|\n");
            printf("|              |                   |                    |              |\n");
            x <= x_end + pow(10, -15);////////------
            double MC = MyCos(x, eps) * MyCos(x, eps);
            double XD = x * cos(3 * x) * x * cos(3 * x);
            d = sqrt(fabs(MC - XD));////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            printf("|  %10.6f  |  %15.10f  | %15.10f    |   %f   |\n", x, MyCos(x, eps), x*cos(3 * x), d);


            printf("|______________|___________________|____________________|______________|\n");
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            printf(" ______________ ___________________ ____________________ ______________ \n");
            printf("|_______x______|___MyFunction(x)___|_____x*cos(3*x)_____|_______d______|\n");
            printf("|              |                   |                    |              |\n");
            for (x; x <= x_end + pow(10, -15); x = x + dx)//шаг.
            {
                double MC = MyCos(x, eps) * MyCos(x, eps);
                double XD = x * cos(3 * x) * x * cos(3 * x);
                d = sqrt(fabs(MC - XD));
                //d = sqrt(fabs(MyCos(x, eps) - x * cos(3 * x)));///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                printf("|  %10.6f  |  %15.10f  | %15.10f    |   %f   |\n", x, MyCos(x, eps), x*cos(3 * x), d);

            }
            printf("|______________|___________________|____________________|______________|\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Введите x_ideal" << endl;
    cin >> x_ideal;

    printf(" _____________ ___________________ ____________________ ______________ \n");
    printf("|______eps____|___MyFunction(x)___|_____x*cos(3*x)_____|_______d______|\n");
    printf("|             |                   |                    |              |\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        double e = pow(0.1, i);
        double MC = MyCos(x_ideal, e) * MyCos(x_ideal, e);
        double XD = x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal) * x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal);
        //d = sqrt(fabs(MyCos(x_ideal, e) - x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal)));
        //while (fabsl(MyCos - (x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal))) >= eps);
        d = sqrt(fabs(MC - XD));
        printf("|  %9.7f  |  %15.10f  | %15.10f    |   %f   |\n", e, MyCos(x_ideal, e), x_ideal*cos(3 * x_ideal), d);
    }
    printf("|_____________|___________________|____________________|______________|\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int OneP(int q)
{
    int a = -1;
    for (int w = 0; w < q; w++)
    {
        a = (-1) * a;
    }
    return a;
}


double fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n > 0)
    {
        return n * fact(n - 1);
    }
}


double MyCos(double x, double eps)
{
    double sum = 0, a;

    for (int k = 0; fabs(OneP(k + 1) * pow(3, 2 * k) * pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / fact(2 * k) + OneP(k) * pow(3, 2 * k + 2) * pow(x, 2 * k + 3) / fact(2 * k + 2)) > eps; k++)
    {
        a = OneP(k + 1) * pow(3, 2 * k) * pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / fact(2 * k);
        sum = sum + a;
    }
    return sum;
}`#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double MyCos(double, double);
double fact(int);
int OneP(int);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    double eps, d, x, x_start, x_end, dx, x_ideal;// невязка, погрешность - остановка расчета, начальный х, конечный х, 
    //шаг вычисления, х для вычисления значений различной точностью
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Введите точность эпсилон: ";
        cin >> eps;
        if (eps <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Точность должна быть вещественным положительным числом" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }

        cout << "Введите начальный x_start: ";
        cin >> x_start;
        x = x_start;

        cout << "Введите конечный x_end: ";
        cin >> x_end;

        cout << "Введите интервал delta_x: ";
        cin >> dx;

        if (dx <= 0 || eps < 0)
        {
            cout << "Введите верные данные" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }

        else if (x_start >= x_end)
        {
            printf(" ______________ ___________________ ____________________ ______________ \n");
            printf("|_______x______|___MyFunction(x)___|_____x*cos(3*x)_____|_______d______|\n");
            printf("|              |                   |                    |              |\n");
            x <= x_end + pow(10, -15);////////------
            double MC = MyCos(x, eps) * MyCos(x, eps);
            double XD = x * cos(3 * x) * x * cos(3 * x);
            d = sqrt(fabs(MC - XD));////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            printf("|  %10.6f  |  %15.10f  | %15.10f    |   %f   |\n", x, MyCos(x, eps), x*cos(3 * x), d);


            printf("|______________|___________________|____________________|______________|\n");
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            printf(" ______________ ___________________ ____________________ ______________ \n");
            printf("|_______x______|___MyFunction(x)___|_____x*cos(3*x)_____|_______d______|\n");
            printf("|              |                   |                    |              |\n");
            for (x; x <= x_end + pow(10, -15); x = x + dx)//шаг.
            {
                double MC = MyCos(x, eps) * MyCos(x, eps);
                double XD = x * cos(3 * x) * x * cos(3 * x);
                d = sqrt(fabs(MC - XD));
                //d = sqrt(fabs(MyCos(x, eps) - x * cos(3 * x)));///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                printf("|  %10.6f  |  %15.10f  | %15.10f    |   %f   |\n", x, MyCos(x, eps), x*cos(3 * x), d);

            }
            printf("|______________|___________________|____________________|______________|\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Введите x_ideal" << endl;
    cin >> x_ideal;

    printf(" _____________ ___________________ ____________________ ______________ \n");
    printf("|______eps____|___MyFunction(x)___|_____x*cos(3*x)_____|_______d______|\n");
    printf("|             |                   |                    |              |\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        double e = pow(0.1, i);
        double MC = MyCos(x_ideal, e) * MyCos(x_ideal, e);
        double XD = x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal) * x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal);
        //d = sqrt(fabs(MyCos(x_ideal, e) - x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal)));
        //while (fabsl(MyCos - (x_ideal * cos(3 * x_ideal))) >= eps);
        d = sqrt(fabs(MC - XD));
        printf("|  %9.7f  |  %15.10f  | %15.10f    |   %f   |\n", e, MyCos(x_ideal, e), x_ideal*cos(3 * x_ideal), d);
    }
    printf("|_____________|___________________|____________________|______________|\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int OneP(int q)
{
    int a = -1;
    for (int w = 0; w < q; w++)
    {
        a = (-1) * a;
    }
    return a;
}


double fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n > 0)
    {
        return n * fact(n - 1);
    }
}


double MyCos(double x, double eps)
{
    double sum = 0, a;

    for (int k = 0; fabs(OneP(k + 1) * pow(3, 2 * k) * pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / fact(2 * k) + OneP(k) * pow(3, 2 * k + 2) * pow(x, 2 * k + 3) / fact(2 * k + 2)) > eps; k++)
    {
        a = OneP(k + 1) * pow(3, 2 * k) * pow(x, 2 * k + 1) / fact(2 * k);
        sum = sum + a;
    }
    return sum;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите начальное значение и модифицируйте слагаемое на каждом обороте цикла согласно формуле.

```
sum = 0
item = x
i = 1
do {
   item =  - item * x * x * 3.0 * 3.0 / (2 * i * (2 * i - 1))
   sum += item
   i++  
} while (fabs(item) >= eps);
```